# Append Element to Xml file with Php

Tags: php, xml

I got Xml File like

```
<root>
<firstchild id="1">
<page name="main">
</page>
</firstchild>
</root>
```

I want to add page for firstchild id="1" in php. How can I add?

```
$xml='<page name="second"></page>';
    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->load($filename);
    $fragment = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
    $fragment->appendXML($xml);
    $doc->documentElement->appendChild($fragment);
    $doc->save($filename);
```

Is there not any method appendXml?
I may add it like

```
 `<page name="second">
<inlude file="1.png"></inlude>
<inlude file="2.png"></inlude>
</page>`
```

I need Shortest Way to Append it

Comment: Add the PHP code that shows you have tried

Comment: This has been asked over and over again in SO. Just take a look at related questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7098093/how-to-append-to-a-xml-file-with-php-preferably-with-simplexml?rq=1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2393270/use-domdocument-to-append-elements-in-a-xml-file?rq=1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using DOMDocument, that's what you need:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($filename);
$firstchild = $doc->getElementsByTagName('firstchild')->item(0);
$newPage = $doc->createDocumentFragment();
$newPage->appendXML('<page name="second">
<inlude file="1.png"></inlude>
<inlude file="2.png"></inlude>
</page>');
$firstchild->appendChild($newPage);
$doc->save(filename);
```

Comment: Thanks it is almost what i need.

Answer (score 1):

Use `addChild` and `addAttribute`:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($data);
$page = $xml->firstchild->addChild("page");
$page->addAttribute("name", "Page name");
echo $xml->saveXML();
```

**Demo:** http://codepad.org/u78S8rFK

Comment: Thank its really short method. but firstly I need find id attr 1